# Phonegap 3.7.0 e-mail file from input[type=file]

Tags: php, android, ajax, cordova, email

I'm having a problem with sending a file from an app I'm developing with phonegap.
I'm new to phonegap, so I might be trying to solve this in an entirely wrong way, so let me describe the the end goal first.

I'm developing a car rental app, I need to make a contact form, so users can leave an order to rent a car.
The form requires user to put in some basic information, like name and phone number, and also attach a photo or a scan of driver's license.

I was able to figure out the basic info part. I'm using $.ajax dataType: 'jsonp', to send the data to the server and then simply e-mail it to my client's address.

But I can find a way to send the file to the server.
I'm using an input[type=file] field to let the user choose what file to upload.
I've tried uploading file using FileTransfer, but apparently input[type=file] gives you some fake file path, that can't be directly used by FileTransfer.upload()

Problem is, I can't understand how can I get a proper file path for FileTransfer.upload function.

I've tried doing it another way, by reading the file using FileReader.
I tried reading the file and setting an image src to the result, but it doesn't work (it show broken image icon instead of an image, the same code works on PC).
I also tried to output it as text, that does output some data (so why doesn't it work for image src?).

Because I did manage to output the data read from the file as text I thought I will send that to the server and save it.

So here is how the code would look like:
On input change I read the file into a global variable

```
$(".file1").change(function(e){
    var caster = e.target;
    var files = caster.files;

    if(FileReader && files && files.length) {
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.onloadend = function(e) {
            //$(".image").attr("src",e.target.result);
            window.file1base64 = e.target.result;
        }
        fr.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    }
});
```

Then, when user presses a button, I run FileTransfer.upload and then check every 0.1 seconds, whether the file upload is complete

```
function uploadSuccess(r) {
    $(".output").append(" Success ");
    window.fileStatus = true;
}

function uploadError(error) {
    $(".output").append(" Error "+error.code+" ");
    window.fileStatus = true;
    window.fileError = error.code;
}

function uploadFile() {
    $(".output").append(" uploadFile ");
    file = $('.file1').val().split('\\').pop();
    $(".output").append(" File-"+file+" ");

    if(file){
        $(".output").append(" fileExists ");
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = file;
        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
        options.chunkedMode = false;
        options.headers = {
            Connection: "close"
        };

        $(".output").append(" FileUploadOptions ");
        window.fileStatus = false;
        window.fileError = '';

        //fileuri = $(".image").attr("src");
        fileuri = window.file1base64;

        $(".output").append(" fileuri ");
        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(fileuri, encodeURI("http://***.***/savefile.php"), uploadSuccess, uploadError, options);

        $(".output").append(" upload ");
        checkFile();
    }
}

function checkFile() {
    if(!window.fileStatus) {
        $(".output").append(" check ");
        setTimeout(checkFile, 100);
        return;
    }
}
```

After some checks, it prints out Error 3 and I can't figure out what that means or how to fix it.

Server side code is simply this:
Get the file and save it

```
$dir_name = dirname(__FILE__)."/uploadedimages/";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $dir_name."test.txt");
```

But no file is created on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `FormData` object to get the form data (including input file) and submit it this way:

```
var data = new FormData($('#yourFormID')[0]);
$.ajax({
        url: serverURL,
        data: data,
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){

        },
        success: function(data){

        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the FILEURL in some variable and image in some html image element and then use it to transfer the image.

like this:

```
 function onPgCameraSuccess(imageData) {

    fileEntry.file(
    function(fileObj) {
            var previewImage= document.getElementById('SomeImageElement');
            fileName=imageData.substr(imageData.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            fileURL=imageData;
            previewImage.src =imageData;
            $('#SomeTextBox').val(fileName);
        });
}

function SubmitPhoto(){
    var uOptions = new FileUploadOptions();
    var ft = new FileTransfer();

    uOptions .fileKey = "keyofyourfileonserver";
    uOptions .fileName = fileName;
    uOptions .mimeType = "image/jpeg"; 
    uOptions .httpMethod = "POST";
    uOptions .params = params;



    ft.upload(fileURL,
        urlofsvc,
        photoSuccess,
        photoFail,
        uOptions,
        true
    );}
```